# Please recommend a gaming laptop for my daughter

Tags: laptop, gaming

17 inches. i7 can play overwatch.

Gaming laptop.

Bigger screen the better

resolution full HD 1920 1080

Additional detail similar to this guy
from: https://www.reddit.com/r/SuggestALaptop/comments/auc5am/i_want_to_buy_laptop_for_my_daughter/

- **Total budget and country of purchase:** Indonesia. Budget $1k to $2k
- **Do you prefer a 2 in 1 form factor, good battery life or best specifications for the money? Pick or include any that apply.** Prefer
- **How important is weight and thinness to you?** Not much
- **Which OS do you require? Windows, Mac, Chrome OS, Linux.** Windows
- **Do you have a preferred screen size? If indifferent, put N/A.** 17 inch or larger full HD
- **Are you doing any CAD/video editing/photo editing/gaming? List which programs/games you desire to run.** Gaming. Video editing. CAD
- **If you're gaming, do you have certain games you want to play? At what settings and FPS do you want?** Overwatch. Full HD. 60 FPS. But 30 is okay
- **Any specific requirements such as good keyboard, reliable build quality, touch-screen, finger-print reader, optical drive or good input devices (keyboard/touchpad)?** Nothing. Touch screen is awesome but not necessary
- **Leave any finishing thoughts here that you may feel are necessary and beneficial to the discussion.** Anything you wish

Reddit recommends
https://www.tokopedia.com/apasuscomputer78/msi-gp73-8re-467-i7-8750h-8gb-256gb-1tb-gtx1060-6gb-w10?trkid=f=Ca0000L144,146,150,151,167,168,171,174,175,176,177,178,463P0W0S0Sh00Co0Po0Fr0Cb0_src=search_page=1_ob=3_q=MSI+GP73_bmexp=18_po=1_catid=289_bmexp=18&lt=/searchproduct%20-%20p1%20-%20product MSI GP73. Unless I found better one I am going to go with that.

Comment: One thing to consider.  Buying a laptop with a screen >19 inches is expensive, I would consider buying a separate monitor and connecting it to the laptop if you truly want a large screen experience.

Comment: 17 inches. Also why large screen is expensive on laptop? Monitors are not expensive.

Comment: One reason is they have to be super durable so they don't break easily.  Monitors have a much thicker frame, and heavy duty.  Plus monitors are stationary are not subjected to abuse.  I have heard many stories of people sitting on their laptop screen, but none on a monitor.

Answer (score 1):

### [MSI GL63 8SE-054 | Rp26,352,888 + Rp594,142 Shipping](https://www.newegg.com/global/id-en/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA7AB8UJ9875)

[image: MSI GL63 8SE-054]

This machine is more than capable of playing the most computationally intensive of triple AAA titles at stable fps with features specifically tuned to gaming (anti-ghosting keyboard) and ready to ship to Indonesia today.

- RTX 2060 6 GB
- i7-8750H
- 16 GB Memory
- 1 TB HDD
- 128 GB NVMe SSD
- FHD @ 120 Hz